# Create scheduled task with power shell in a Remote Machine

Tags: powershell, task, scheduled-tasks

How can one create a task in task scheduler on a remote machine using Power shell?

Answer (score 2):

To create a task in the scheduler you can use the New-ScheduledTaskAction, New-ScheduledTaskTrigger and Register-ScheduledTask cmdlets - detailed info can be found here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/13/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/

Here's an example:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' `
         -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command "& {get-eventlog -logname Application -After ((get-date).AddDays(-1)) | Export-Csv -Path c:\fso\applog.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation}"'

$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "AppLog" -Description "Daily dump of Applog"
```

Running Powershell remotely requires a few configuration changes, which you can find out about here: https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/